# Calling user.getIdTokenResult(true) in Firebase causes all document listeners to return latest data again

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

It seem that calling user.getIdTokenResult(true) causes all my document listeners to resend the latest data.

This is causing unnecessary processing locally as the data has not actually changed in Firestore.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Do these count as reads in Firestore?

At the moment I am reloading the token on each page initialization to make sure the latest custom claims are present and this is causing all my listeners to fire each time the user changes a page.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question, and the issue of force refreshing a token affecting listeners is unheard of but a possibility. Maybe a Firebase could know more but it is highly specialized to the listener logic, which isn't documented.

Instead, I would suggest using `onIdTokenChanged()` to react to custom claims rather than refreshing them frequently.  if that method isn't fast enough, I suggest using a listener to a database that reacts to the users profile being updated with a flag for custom claims

Comment: @DIGIByte Yes using a listener on a database is a good suggestion.  I have done this for another project and it works well.  I have also removed most of the token refreshes from my code as they were not needed.  I am still curious as to why this happens and if it is a firebase bug though so I will contact Firebase support about it.

Comment: it wouldn't be a bug since the logic behind it would be swapping out one user for another, and if one had permission to read in a secure collection vs any changes to the user or custom claims, this makes sense to revoke/refresh the listeners